# Constructing an array with VBA that will contain the contents of each column in an Excel file

Tags: arrays, loops, excel, vba

I am working with an excel file that contains 5 columns, each for a distinct element. 
I tried to create a collection of Columns, where each element of that collection will contain the data from the rows in each column. I started with an array like this:

```
Dim Column(1 To 5) As ColumnsInFile
    Column(1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    Column(2) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    Column(3) = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    Column(4) = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown))
    Column(5) = Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
```

Later I would like to perform a function on the contents of each column one by one.

My problem is that it seems I could have a simpler code for all this - plus that code doesn't work telling me something is not defined.

How could I loop through each Column, so that for each column, the code will get the content through a loop? Instead of defining B2, something more generic, that starts with the first column and goes to the next one, and then the next one.. cause, the problem is, what if I had 400 columns..I couldn't juste define it that way..it would be too long..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define your variable you need to be using `variant` and the name `column` is a property of a range and shouldn't be used as a name:

```
dim cols() as variant, lastrow as long, lastcol as long 

'find last row and column 
lastrow = cells.find("*", range("A1"), , , xlbyrows, xlprevious).row
lastcol = cells.find("*", range("A1"), , , xlbycolumns, xlprevious).column 

'define your columns
cols = range("A2").resize(lastrow - 1, lastcol)

dim c as long, R as Long 
'cycle through columns
for C = 1 To ubound(cols, 2) ' second dimension is columns

    'cycle through rows
    for R = 1 to ubound(cols, 1) ' first array dimension is rows.

        'do somthing with columns and rows
        debug.print cols(R, C)

    next R
next C
```

[More reading.](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I looked around on the internet and I found some similar method with loops. But this gives me yet another approach!